# How to setup a contract that pays every day/week/month .. XAS from sender to receiver?

Tags: smartcontracts, asch-development, asch

In Asch one can create a new contract with ease.

I wonder how to set up a contact which pays ... XAS (or any other asset) from address1 to address2 every minute/hour/day/etc.

See also: https://github.com/AschPlatform/asch/issues/242

So i would like something like:

`` //every week
{
app.balances.transfer(`xas`, 10, address1, address2)
} ``